# Django models - link group of words to single word in lexicon/dictionary

Tags: django, django-models

Sorry for the lack of a better title. I didn't know how to name what I'm trying to do. Anyways, Django noob trying to do the following:

I'm building a lexicon/dictionary. You search for a word and information about that word is being displayed. But the info also contains related words, grouped into some sort of logical cluster(s).

For instance, you search for the word 'bicycle'. On the same page words like 'unicycle' and 'tricycle' (they are from the same table as the main word) are grouped together under the cluster name 'bicycle types'. Grouping of the words are done by making a group and adding words to that. For this I have the following model (simplified):

**models.py**

```
class Word(models.Model):
    word = models.Charfield()

class WordGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    words = models.ManyToManyField(Word)
```

Then in the admin I can select the group from an inline.

I'm not sure if this is conceptually the way to do it. It crashes python (locally) so I can imagine it's not :)

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: An stack trace of the error would be nice. The model seems to be okay, so it's probably something else, but we need more info to know what coult it be. Wild guess: did you execute a syncdb?

Comment: Yes, did syncdb. I actually said it wrong that it crashes python. What I meant is that trying to create a new wordgroup spikes the CPU to 99%, but no real crash or error (so no stack trace available?). Maybe I should also mention that the table contains 38.000 words, but that really shouldn't be a problem since I use raw_id_fields instead of the standard dropdown in the admin inline.

Comment: I've no idea of what could it be xD anyway, you should update your question with the info you just posted (and maybe the definitions of the inline for `Word` and the model admin for `WordGroup`, if you are not absolutely sure it's correctly defined) so the next person that reads your questions haves a better context to work on an answer.

Answer (score 0):

With some help from a co-worker I managed to get the output I was looking for. The solution was to define an inlinemodeladmin object for the relation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-many-to-many-models).

The problem with not being able to access the wordgroupadmin seems to lie in MySQL. The same setup works in sqlite3, but hangs in MySQL. I'll have to investigate that further.